# Is it possible to post audio files with the python requests library

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm considering using the [Python Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) to post mp3s to an api, but all the examples of posting files in the documentation are for text files. Is it possible to use this library for audio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send *any* sequence of bytes with the library:

```
with open(audiofile, 'rb') as fobj:
    requests.post(url, files={'fieldname': fobj})
```

In fact, the [first multipart-encoded file example](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) in the `requests` documentation posts a binary file:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
    "file": "<censored...binary...data>"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: It seems that in the first example, `files={'fieldname', fobj}` should be `files={'fieldname': fobj}`. Otherwise a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` error occured.

Comment: @Lane: well spotted, yes!